# How to check if a user has privs to access a node in organic groups

Tags: organic-groups

Does someone know what function within Organic Groups I can use to check if a user (the signed in user) as access to a given node? Do you have an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same function you should always use in any context: `node_access('view', $node);`

Modules are expected to use node access hooks to implement access control, so this function will consider all of the modules that may grant or remove access to the given $node object.